# Is there any better way to create an object?

Tags: java, object, constructor

I'm creating a new object from class Student, however, class Student contains an object from class Address and class Address contains an object from class PostCode. I tried to create 3 different objects, is there any better way to do this?

```
public class Main{


public static void main(String[] args) {

    PostCode p1 = new PostCode("Keiraville", "Wollongong", "NSW");
    Address a1 = new Address (17, "Dalas",p1 , "Australia");
    Student s1 = new Student("Huang", 314531, a1, "Csit121");

    s1.print();
```

class Student

```
public class Student {
String name;
int studentID;
Address address;
String courseID;

public Student(String name, int studentID, Address address, String courseID)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.studentID = studentID;
    this.address = address;
    this.courseID = courseID;
}
```

class Address

```
public class Address  {
int streetNumber;
String streetName;
PostCode postCode;
String country;

public Address(int streetNum, String name, PostCode postCode, String country)
{
    this.streetNumber = streetNum;
    this.streetName = name;
    this.postCode = postCode;
    this.country = country;
}
```

class PostCode

```
public class PostCode{
String suburb;
String city;
String state;

public PostCode (String suburb, String city, String state)
{
    this.suburb = suburb;
    this.city = city;
    this.state = state;
}
```

i also tried

```
Student s1 = new Student("Huang", 314531, Address(17, "Dalas", PostCode("Keiraville", "Wollongong", "NSW") , "Australia"), "Csit121");
```

Comment: What's wrong with creating them the way you have?

Comment: I feel it is not an effective way to do it. Because I need to create 3 objects for one student

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both seem perfectly valid ways to create new objects. In your second version, you forgot `new` keyword before Address and PostCode. Otherwise there is really no difference in terms of validity. What you might find is that in the second implementation, you may be going over 80 characters. It is a convention to keep lines short, usually under 80 characters.

In order to print the values of your objects, implementing a print function as you suggested is a valid option but in Java, the convention is to implement a `toString()` method in every class which returns the values as a string. For example, in your PostCode class, it should look something like

```java
public String toString() {
    return " Suburb = " + this.suburb + " City = " + this.city + " State = " this.state;
}
```

And then, you can print the values by

```java
PostCode postCodeObject = new PostCode("Bla", "Bla2", "Bla3");
System.out.println(postCodeObject.toString());
```

If you values are not of the type String, e.g. they could be int e.g. studentid, you can say something like

```java
return Integer.toString(studentid);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the concept of multi level inheritance... use super method in 2 of the class nd pass the parameters to the super... by doing this u have to make only one object nd pass all the parameters to the constructor of that class